# Face the player towards a pushable when raycast hits with an angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a pushing system and I'm having some issues. The player uses a CharacterController which can interact with Rigidbodies in the scene. Currently this works as follows: When a Raycast hits a pushable object in front of the player and presses the push button he will push the object, which all works fine. The issue occurs when the Player is slightly turned away from the pushable and starts pushing. I.e. when the character is off by like 10 degrees, but the ray still hits. The concept I had in mind was calculating the angle of the raycast that hits the pushable cube and rotating the character controller towards the pushable by that angle. The problem is I have no clue how to achieve this. I hope someone can help me with this concept. If anyone has any other concepts or ideas feel free to share them :)

Edit: I've added some scripts

The Character controller part:

```
if (inputDir != Vector2.zero)
    {
        float targetRotation = Mathf.Atan2(inputDir.x, inputDir.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cameraT.eulerAngles.y;
        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetRotation, ref turnSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(turnSmoothTime));
    }

    float targetSpeed = ((running) ? runSpeed : movementSpeed) * inputDir.magnitude;
    currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentSpeed, targetSpeed, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));

    velocityY += Time.deltaTime * gravity;

    Vector3 velocity = transform.forward * currentSpeed + Vector3.up * velocityY;
    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    currentSpeed = new Vector2(controller.velocity.x, controller.velocity.z).magnitude;
```

The Raycast setup and pushstates as off now:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(middle, (forward), out hit, distanceForPush))
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Push") && hit.collider.tag == "PushableLight")
        {
            anim.SetBool("isPushing", true);
            pushForce = playerPushForceLight;
            movementSpeed = pushSpeedLight;
            hit.transform.SendMessage("HitByPlayer", null, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            if (controller.velocity == Vector3.zero)
            {
                anim.SetFloat("pushSpeedAnim", 0f);
            }
            else
            {
                anim.SetFloat("pushSpeedAnim", 1f);
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetButton("Push") && hit.collider.tag == "PushableHeavy")
        {
            anim.SetBool("isPushing", true);
            pushForce = playerPushForceHeavy;
            movementSpeed = pushSpeedHeavy;
            hit.transform.SendMessage("HitByPlayer", null, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            if (controller.velocity == Vector3.zero)
            {
                anim.SetFloat("pushSpeedAnim", 0f);
            }
            else
            {
                anim.SetFloat("pushSpeedAnim", 1f);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isPushing", false);
            pushForce = 0f;
            movementSpeed = walkSpeed;
            hit.transform.SendMessage("HitStopped", null, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

        }
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetBool("isPushing", false);

    }


    AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
    if (stateInfo.fullPathHash == pushStateHash)
    {
        turnSmoothTime = maxTurnSmoothTimePushing;
    }
    else
    {
        turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to align the player with the hit's collision normal.

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(-hit.normal, Vector3.up);
```

This will probably only work well for boxes, though.

Comment: This kind off works, but I'm encountering some more issues right now. I think those issues have to do with the direction the pushForce goes. Currently the direction off the pushForce is:

    Vector3 pushDirection = new Vector3(hit.moveDirection.x, 0, hit.moveDirection.z);

This is based on how the character controller hits the pushable object, but I think this should be replaced with the direction the hit normal is facing. This way the pushable object is always pushed in the direction of the hit normal. The problem is, I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: I would do pushDirection = player.transform.forward, but it really depends on how you want your gameplay to work.